# Hibernate exception at updation using hql

Tags: hibernate

I am trying query

```
update PostImages as p  set  p.isAlbumCover='No'  
where  p.album.name='Profile'  and   p.atom.id=1
```

album is many to one 
and atom is many to one

I am getting exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set is_album_cover='No' where name='Profile' and aid=1' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 8 more
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> 'set is_album_cover='No' where name='Profile' and aid=1'

[mysql keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)
The "name" may be the reserved word.
You have to make a mapping from name to [name]

Try this if you're using annotation in you bean definition.

```
 @Column(name = "[NAME]",.....)
 public String getName()
```